# How can I get Ender Bees in Agrarian Skies?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

One of the final bee-related quests requires you to breed bees to produce certus combs. In order to get this bee, you need to have access to ender bees. How can I get ender bees in Agrarian Skies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 2.1.1 of the Agrarian Skies pack, Ender Bees are a reward for the "Work Harder" quest in the Bees and Trees quest tree.

[image: Ender bees as a reward.]

Aside from that, you can only get Ender Bees with an Ex Nihilo artificial hive in The End, surrounded by End Stone.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, I placed 5 scented hives in the End in various positions.  2 were in the center of a 5x5x10 block (in the center of each 5x5x5 cube) with views of the sky, 3 were placed on top of the 5x5x10 rectangular prism.  I got 2 End hives, both from on top of the cubes.